# On Scrivener, Hitting Return Key is Causing Double-Space when it shouldn't

Tags: formatting, scrivener

At the end of a paragraph I hit return ONCE. (I check to make sure, using format - show invisibles, and yes, there is one return.) Yet, even though I my entire document is single spaced, Scrivener inserts a double spaced line break that I can't seem to get rid of. I tried selecting the whole thing again, just to make sure, clicking on single space, but again everything is single-spaced EXCEPT the line after the return. I tried typing a single word and hitting return -- same thing, double-spaced.  This does not happen in pages, only when I am using Scrivener.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: I don't use Scrivener, but check that there isn't an option to increase the space at the end of a paragraph (or the beginning) like there is in Word.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the text.
2. Click the <sub>[image]</sub> ‘Set the line spacing’ button.
3. Choose ‘Other…’.
4. Set ‘Line height multiple’ to 1 and ‘Paragraph spacing before’ and ‘after’ to 0.0.

   [image]
5. Click OK.

To make this apply to all new documents, go to Scrivener Preferences → Formatting and choose ‘Use Formatting in Current Editor’.

[image]